# Modifying the src attribute of an image tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to perform a find/replace on the src attribute of an image tag, to remove part of the filename of the image. I assume I need to use `str.replace()`, but I'm not sure how to write the regex to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

The `src` attribute is currently

`http://domain.com/path/to/file/D063DC58-6051-4B24-8CDC-D4525F72A150_tn.jpg`

where `/to/file/xxxxxxx_tn.jpg` will vary, with the filename always ending in `_tn.jpg`. I'd like to remove the `_tn` from each instance on the page.

Comment: looks like grabbing facebook images, from _q (quick /small thumb) to _n (normal size) ;)

Comment: jQuery is certainly an option. It's not grabbing facebook images, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```javascript
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = images[i].src.replace('_tn.jpg', '.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var srcValue = "http://domain.com/path/to/file/D063DC58-6051-4B24-8CDC-D4525F72A150_tn.jpg";

var newSrcValue = srcValue.replace(/[A-Z0-9\-]+_tn/, 'xxxxx_tn');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regular expression.

```
referenceToImage.src = referenceToImage.src.replace('_tn', '');
```

Comment: I'll go ahead and show my ignorance and ask: what's the best way to select the image src? My javascript skills are weak at best.

Comment: By using the `src` property as per the example in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery >= 1.1:

```
$("img").attr("src", function(i, val) {
    return val.replace("_tn.jpg", ".jpg");
});
```